# Add gradient to Vuetify v-card :img

Tags: image, vue.js, vuetify.js, gradient, vcf-vcard

```
<v-card
  :img="require('@/core/assets/homeBg.png')"
>
</v-card>
```

The image is displaying as it should but i just want to know if there is anyway to **apply gradient to that image** .

(actually i just wanted to darken the image so that the texts infront of it will be more readable )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add your own style with linear-gradient and image:

```
<v-card 
    style="background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)), url(require('@/core/assets/homeBg.png')) center center / cover no-repeat"
>
</v-card>
```

Notice: inside `url()` you should have path/url to the image. Control darkness by changing opacity in `rgbA` colors. Image position (`center center`), image size (`cover`) and repeat (`no-repeat`) are copied the same as `img` prop from `v-card` generates them.